# JSONDecodeError in Python

Tags: python, json, flask

I am building a whatsapp bot with flask but I encountered a json issue when processing data from an api endpoint.
Here is a snippet of the code throwing the error:

```
url = f"https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/thesaurus/json/{word}?key={api_key}"
response = requests.get(url)
api_response = json.loads(response.text)
if response.status_code == 200:
    for data in api_response:
        try:
```

The error itself:

```
 File "/home/micmusk/mysite/app.py", line 81, in get_dictionary_response
api_response = json.loads(response.text)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Funny thing is that, the line of code works for me on my local machine when I used localhost but now that I deployed it starts throwing errors. I tried using `requests.get(url).json` it still throws the same error. I use Python 3.6

Comment: Print `response.text` and see what its value is.  Check the status code first...maybe it failed.

Comment: error shows that it doesn't get any data. You should check `status_code` before you try to get `json()`. You can also use `try/except` to catch error and display `response.text` to see what you get. Sometimes servers may send warning for bots but if you use official API with `key` then it shouldn't send warning. Other problem can makes server on which you run it - it also can blocks access to other servers to block spamers.